# TextBox Deletes GridView Data is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I Have a `TextBox` and a `Label` inside of a GridView.  My issue is that when I update the GridView and the `TextBox` is empty it deletes the data in the Label (which makes sense).  My question is, is it possible to keep the `TextBox` empty and update without losing any data?

c#:

```
Private void Update()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBox timeR = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("SitUps") as TextBox;
            if (timeR.Text.Length < 10)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    sb.Append("UPDATE bleaTest SET SitUps = '");
                    sb.Append((row.FindControl("SitUps") as TextBox).Text);
                    sb.Append("'");
                    sb.Append(" WHERE id = ");
                    sb.Append(Convert.ToInt32((row.FindControl("ID") as Label).Text));
                    sb.Append(" ");

                }
            }
            else
            {
                timeR.Text = "Number is too high!";
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    sb.Append("UPDATE bleaTest SET SitUps = '");
                    sb.Append((row.FindControl("SitUps") as TextBox).Text);
                    sb.Append("'");
                    sb.Append(" WHERE id = ");
                    sb.Append(Convert.ToInt32((row.FindControl("ID") as Label).Text));
                    sb.Append(" ");

                }

            }
        }



        string connectiongString = "Data Source=WSCJTCSQ1;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=v2soft;Password=passwordv2soft";
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectiongString);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
        BindData();
        }
```

aspx:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sit Ups">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="SitUps" runat="server" type="number" Text='<%# Eval("SitUps") %>' EnableViewState="True"></asp:TextBox></div>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: If the textbox is empty during the update, what exactly are you trying to update? Please be a little more descriptive.

Comment: Hi jcalabris, if the `TextBox` is empty I want it to do nothing instead it's placing a blank data into the table.  Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Is the gridview only supposed to have a single row, or can it have multiple rows? The basic idea behind this is to only update rows which have been changed since the last update. Is it possible that the row could be changed and set to an empty value? In that case I'm guessing you would need to update the database right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue here's the code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    TextBox tR = row.FindControl("SitUps") as TextBox;
                    if(tR.Text != "")
                    {
                    sb.Append("UPDATE bleaTest SET SitUps = '");
                    sb.Append((row.FindControl("SitUps") as TextBox).Text);
                    sb.Append("'");
                    sb.Append(" WHERE id = ");
                    sb.Append(Convert.ToInt32((row.FindControl("ID") as Label).Text));
                    sb.Append(" ");
                    string connectiongString = "Data Source=WSCJTCSQ1;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=v2soft;Password=passwordv2soft";
                    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectiongString);
                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), myConnection);
                    myConnection.Open();
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    myConnection.Close();

                    }

                }
        BindData();
        }
```

I cleaned up the code and now it checks if the text is not null and proceeds with the update.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you could change `if (timeR.Text.Length < 10)` to `if (timeR.Text.Length < 10 and timeR.Text.Length > 0)`

Comment: on another note, you do realize you are looping through the entire set of rows inside of the loop that moves through the entire set of rows.  you have a foreach inside of the for, both iterating through all rows.

Comment: Yes sorry I was messing around with the code so much I didn't notice that.